# Cannot populate a LinearLayout with specific objects

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm working on a simple messenger app (to learn).

I can successfully login and view the Dashboard Activity. But when Dashboard Activity tries to initialize some "pseudo messages", I get a NullPointer Exception.

**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.messenger.DashboardActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/dirtyBlue">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the "message layout I would like to initialize for each message, and place them in scrollview's linear layout

**message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/dirtyWhite"
    android:onClick="openMsg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/senderUserText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sender Text"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msgText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Message Text!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what's going on in Dashboard Activity.java

**DashboardActivity.java**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    ParseMessages();
}
```

and here's the part where "ParseMessages()" function works.

**Database_IO.java**

```
public static List<Message> msgList;
 public static List<Message> ParseMessageList()
{
    GenerateRandomMessages();
    return msgList;
}
public static void GenerateRandomMessages()
{
    Message message1 = new Message();
    message1.Message = "MSG1";
    message1.senderID = "Sender1";
    message1.recipientID = "Me";
    message1.isRead = false;

    Message message2 = new Message();
    message1.Message = "MSG2";
    message1.senderID = "Sender2";
    message1.recipientID = "Me";
    message1.isRead = true;

    msgList.add(message1);
    msgList.add(message2);
    Log.e("Message 1", message1.Message);
    Log.e("Message 2", message1.Message);
}
```

NullPointerException shows these lines:

```
msgList.add(message1);
msgList.add(message2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to initalize your msgList!**

Optional: you might want to correct message2 (you are currently only assigning data to message1)

**Do this:**

in

```
 public static void GenerateRandomMessages()
{
//initialize msgList
msgList = new ArrayList();
```

//if you want to correct message2

```
   Message message2 = new Message();
    message2.Message = "MSG2";
    message2.senderID = "Sender2";
    message2.recipientID = "Me";
    message2.isRead = true;

    msgList.add(message1);
    msgList.add(message2);
    Log.e("Message 1", message1.Message);
//here also, you were using message 1
    Log.e("Message 2", message2.Message);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, i fixed message2 part. And initializing msgList fixed the issue. However, all i see is an empty activity with no message.xml items in it. I believe there's something else wrong here. Sill marking as answer since it fixed my crash.

Edit: Never mind, i just remembered that i commented out that part for debugging. Thanks and sorry!